# Getting a specific word from files in a larger directory(workspace)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need to document in word what are the table names used for my application and also in which classses they are used.

It is a very big application. I did a file seaarch in workspace using extend class name (Testtransformation) and got 142 java files referencing table names.

I need to fetch the table names and also respective classes for this.

So, thought of writing a java code first to get the list of java files extending Testtransformation and trying to the tables names in it and respective class name in a list, so not to manully copy paste it.

is it possible to do that?

eg: of my one class  to do search: I need to fetch the class name AddCustomer and also table name H005Table

```
 public class AddCustomer extends Testtranformation
    {
             ...//codes.....
                         ....
                 SetIn.SetParms( "H005Table",       // Tablename
                             m.getNumber())     
     }
```

Comment: have you considered using grep?

Answer (score 1):

Using a BufferedReader read for the lines till "public class" line and when the pointer is at "public class" line check whether it has "extends ". If yes, add the Class name into a list. Thats how we can do this in java. A loop which runs for all the listFiles()

If the environment is Unix, I would do something like the below rather than a java program.

> find . -name "*.java" | xargs grep "extends classname"

Comment: +1 btw,  the 'xargs' is at least superfluous. find . -name "*.java" | grep "extends classname" works fine. add a -n if you want to know the line number as well.